# How to resolve the measure string calculation between two different graphics?

Tags: c#, winforms

I got the graphics from PaintEventArgs and measure the string by MeasureString method.

```
Public class CustomControl: Control
{

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    Graphics g= pe.Graphics;
    SizeF size = g.MeasureString("Print a character and preview",font)
}

}
```

> ```
> Output: {Width = 150.813126 Height = 14.6523409}
> Height: 14.6523409
> IsEmpty: false
> Width: 150.813126
> ```

So I can set the above text within text rectangle width = 154, Height = 18)

If I have used the above scenario for PrintDocument which give different solution

```
public class CustomPrintDocument : PrintDocument
{
    protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
Graphics g= e.Graphics;
    SizeF size = g.MeasureString("Print a character and preview",font)

}
}
```

> ```
> Output: {Width = 157.093277 Height = 15.2628555}
> Height: 15.2628555
> IsEmpty: false
> Width: 157.093277
> ```

In above scenario i cannot draw the full text in rectangle within in the CustomPrintDocument and Cannot get the Graphics from CustomControl because CustomControl not in active when preview the document.

My query I need to draw the text in CustomPrintDocument like CustomControl

Screenshot
[image]

Note: 
I do not want to change the font of the text to fit in CustomPrintDocument

Please suggest me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: There is insufficient information to answer your question. You _should_ be using the same logic for layout in both cases, but using specific metrics from the current `Graphics`. Why can't you _"draw the full text in rectangle"_? As long as you account for the actual dimensions of the space in which you're drawing, and the _current_ metrics of the string you're drawing, it should work. Please fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] showing clearly what you've tried, and explain _precisely_ what that code does and what you want instead.

Comment: You will have to make your Column A wider for your print out.  I'm guessing you are trying to avoid that type of code.

Comment: The scaling for the screen and the printer is slightly different.  Your monitor operates at 96 pixels per inch, PrintDocument operates at 100 pixels per inch.  100 / 96 ~= 1.042 and 157.09 / 150.81 ~= 1.042.  So you'll have to tweak the scaling a bit to get an exact match.  Do keep in mind that the monitor can also operate at higher settings (120, 144 are common) so hard-coding the box size is not a great idea.  Just make the print layout completely independent from the control layout, giving them the same font is just not necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your response. Is any reference link available for this ?